# Joomla, I want a 500 http code when db connection fails

Tags: php, error-handling, joomla, http-headers

How can I change the code so that whenever Joomla fails to connect to the DB, the http header code is 500 Internal Server Error. Currently, it displays a message saying 'Database Error: Unable to connect to database' but the http status code is 200.

This is on Joomla 1.5 / PHP 5.3.3

Please note that I'm not familiar with Joomla, editing someone else's code, so I don't know how error handling in joomla works.

I tried reading the code at ./libraries/joomla/error but I'm still unsure to where the error message is really thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/libraries/joomla/factroy.php
```

Error is written in `_createDBO` method.

Answer (score 2):

Just this:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
```

or if using FastCGI:

```
header('Status: 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
```

Comment: I know that, I just don't know where to put it.

Comment: I need to know the file in joomla that is responsible, or acts as a template to display that error.